# implementing cancan permission for specific records through joins query in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, cancan

I want to give current user ability to manage specific records coming from menus table through the following rails active record query:

```
Menu.joins(location: :owner_associations).where('owner_associations.user_id' => current_user.id,'owner_associations.place_type'=>"Location")
```

I am doing this in my ability.rb class:

```
@menu = Menu.joins(location: :owner_associations).where('owner_associations.user_id' => user.id,'owner_associations.place_type'=>"Location")
can :manage, @menu
```

and in view i am checking for this as :

```
<%@menu = Menu.joins(location: :owner_associations).where('owner_associations.user_id' => current_user.id,'owner_associations.place_type'=>"Location")%>
<% if can? :manage, @menu %>
   //display menu here
```

but its not working. Can somebody explain?

Comment: what are the fields in menu?

Comment: @Sontya if u are asking w.r.t query , the query is perfectly fine. i tested it on rails console.

Comment: I am not asking about query, I am asking about fields in your menu table

Comment: id, location_id, title, description, ingredients